# Solving $x \cdot x + 2x = d$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some help with this equation

$$x \cdot x + 2x = d$$

I want to find value of $x$, I already know value of $d$.
I want to modify this equation like $x = \ ?$
I need a single $x$ to be on left side and $d$ variable on right side so I can calculate $x$ for different values of $d$ with ease.
Please help. Many thanks

Comment: Quadratic formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try things like completing the square or the quadratic formula. My personal preference is the quadratic formula. Move d to the other side, and plug in your values.

Here is a link to some good content, like equations and practice problems. I hope this helps!

[Methods](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/SolveQuadraticEqnsII.aspx)

Comment: cool. thanks mate